# Over-the-counter prices of pharmaceutical drugs in the United States

Tags: data-request, usa, medical, finance

I'm looking for a data set containing the over-the-counter prices of pharmaceutical drugs by pharmacy in the United States.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this data has some business value and, hence is often available only at a cost. If a non-free solution is sufficient for you, you could try it [here](http://www.fdbhealth.com/fdb-medknowledge-drug-pricing/) and [here](http://www.wolterskluwercdi.com/drug-data/drug-price-history/).

If it's important for you that the data comes free, you might be able to scrape it of this [website](https://www.goodrx.com) which contains information for many drugs and pharmacies all over the United States but has the disadvantage that these online prices need not necessarily be in line with over-the-counter prices as there are sometimes discounts on the website. Still a good source with a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

GoodRX has an API that you can use, easier than scraping. [GoodRX Developer API](https://www.goodrx.com/developer)